# Testing Adobe Flash - SWF Stack Corruption

Tags: exploit, flash, internet-explorer

For didactic purposes I have a windows 7 VM with IE11 and Adobe Flash 18.0.0.203.
Also, I must test if [CVE-2017-2988](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/41421/) can be executed on it.
I have downloaded the stackbad.swf, inserted it in an index.html file and  tried to open the index.html file in IE11, but can't see any effect.
Something like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="1" height="1" >
    <param name="movie" value="stackbad.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />

    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1" height="1" src="stackbad.swf" allowScriptAccess="always"   Play="true"/>
    </object>
```

What should I see here? How can I test that this works under my VM?